# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x7fff86b93f10) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86bb7bb0). error in flutter to native conversion

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to add a native code in my flutter application. When I am not passing any arguments it is working fine, but when I am adding any argument it is not working.

Following is my flutter code:

```
  static const platform = const MethodChannel("com.example.final");

  initiatelinkedinshare() async {
    String url = 'api_link_here' + id;
    String value;
    try {
      value =
          await platform.invokeMethod("initiatelinkedinshare", {"text": url});
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    print(value);
  }
```

Following is my swift code:

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let CHANNEL = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.final", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    
    CHANNEL.setMethodCallHandler { [unowned self] (methodCall, result) in
        if methodCall.method == "initiatelinkedinshare" {
            let text = methodCall.arguments as! String
            result("Hello from swift")
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=" + text) else {
                return //be safe
              }
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                result("Hi from Swift")
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                result("Hi from Swift")
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, it shows the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x7fff86b93f10) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86bb7bb0).
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `methodCall.arguments` is a dictionary, not a string. Force casting it to a string throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this error Because `methodCall.argument` is of type `NSDictionary` equivalent to Map in Dart and you are force casting it to `string` type. This how you can solve it

`methodCall.arguments.value(forKey:"text") as! String`